# Text not going underneath other portion of text

Tags: html, css

My text does not seem to want to go underneath this portion of text! 
http://prntscr.com/1x2zju

No matter how hard we try to get it to go under it, it doesn't go below it.

```
.avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.name {
  color: #3B63DB;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica, 'SEGOEUIL', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 3px;
  float: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='post'>
<img class='avatar' src='http://cppsgang.com/images/person.png'>
        <p class='name'>Thomas A.</p>
        <p class='text'>Hello there! This is my status update. Unfortunately, it will not go below my name. Is there any way I can put it below my name, or is it stuck like this forever? I have to add more in, blah blah blah, to show you how it eventually breaks apart - just not underneath the name. Thanks for all the help you can give!</p>
        <a href='system/posts/delete.php?id=$row[0]'/><span style='color: red;'>Delete</span></a>

</div>
```

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/QUFx5/

Comment: When asking HTML/CSS questions, please provide parsed HTML output, without PHP (it needs to be reproducible!) Also, a http://jsfiddle.net test case of the problem is usually helpful in addition to the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT WITH WORKING

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/GWdmb/)

HTML

```
<div id='post'>
    <img class='avatar' src='http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-35-35-9.jpg'>
            <p class='name'>Thomas A.</p>
            <p class='text'>Hello there! This is my status update. Unfortunately, it will not go below my name. Is there any way I can put it below my name, or is it stuck like this forever? I have to add more in, blah blah blah, to show you how it eventually breaks apart - just not underneath the name. Thanks for all the help you can give!</p>
            <a href='system/posts/delete.php?id=$row[0]'/><span style='color: red;'>Delete</span></a>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.name {
  color: #3B63DB;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica, 'SEGOEUIL', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left:45px;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Floating it left causes it all to go below the avatar and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your jsfiddle.net.

This thing worked for me:

```
.avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.name {
  color: #3B63DB;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica, 'SEGOEUIL', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

I have removed float from name and text class. Also, increased the width & height of avatar to 50px each.

The new code I tried which works according to your requirement:

```
.avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.name {
  color: #3B63DB;
  font-size: 15px;

}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Helvetica, 'SEGOEUIL', sans-serif;
  margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Comment: I got it to work, also used a negative integer in margin-top which got it to work (-15px) in text. However, it seems it is way too close to the avatar. Doing a simple &nbsp; works on only the first line. margin-left doesn't appear to be working. Any ideaS?